# Rails : Updating a table on form submit

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, render

I have a model Leave which stores the information related to Leaves taken by students. I have a view, which shows various types of reports generated from the Leave table.

When this 'report' page is opened for the first time in the browser, it shows all the data present in the table.

Now I have a form which queries the Leave Table and render table/partials on the submit button.

This table is rendered in a partial '_report.html.erb'. When the 'report' page is opened it gets rendered.

```
<%= render 'report' %>
```

Now when I submit the form, the whole view is refreshed, that is not what I want. I just want to refresh the table/partial not the whole view. How should I go about it..?

Comment: @jvnill i first tried it using ajax and jquery for creating a dynamic table. Then i wasn't able to add the Rails link in them. It was working fine though. Then i heard about rendering partials, so i thought i could use this to create a table in which i will be able to add the rails link. And it's working fine, but instead of refreshing the _report.html.erb, it's refreshing the whole view.

Comment: i meant what have you tried to tackle the "selective refresh" part?

Comment: that's what I am trying to figure out. As I am new to the rails, i am not able to redirect my brain in the right direction.

Comment: try looking at http://asciicasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Comment: @jvnill it worked like a charm. can u plz tell me if i can render the same partial view from different controller methods?

Comment: yep just include the controller name like `render partial: 'users/partial'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25773/discussion-between-ph3n0m-aks-and-jvnill)